# communicate with mongodb from aws lambda function

Tags: python, mongodb, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, aws-lambda

I have created a lambda function and executed a program which include numpy  by uploading zip file and it executed successfully.

but when I connect the mongodb using public ip then it throughing exception as 
"time out".
Please help me .
thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you running the mongo instance? How is the firewall/Securitygroup configured.

Comment: mondodb is running on aws ec2.

Comment: thank you very much.  when I allow publicly (0.0.0.0/0) then it accessing but we can't allow on all IP . so how to allow 27017 port for lambda function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your Lambda function is unable to connect to your EC2 instance which is running MongoDB.

This is most likely a SecurityGroup issue.

You should allow your lambda VPC to connect to your EC2 instance. In essence it means that you will assign a VPC, subnet and Security group to your lambda. Afterwards you can allow the security group of the lambda to access the security group of your mongo.

Detailed instructions on how to add a vpc/subnet/sg to your lambda can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html)

> You add VPC information to your Lambda function configuration using
>   the VpcConfig parameter, either at the time you create a Lambda
>   function (see CreateFunction), or you can add it to the existing
>   Lambda function configuration (see UpdateFunctionConfiguration).

Comment: Thanks Thomas for your time. It helped me.